# Call out of an Array, objectAtIndex

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, label

I have an `Array` with 10 Objects. I take the first Object and put it into my `Label` with a `String`.

Then I want to have a Method that increases the `objectAtIndex` by 1.

This is my Code :

```
//.m
@interface GameViewController () {

   NSInteger _labelIndex;
   }
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *playerArray;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *playerLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.playerArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"FIRST", @"SECOND", @"THIRD", @"FOURTH", @"FIFTH", @"SIXT", @"SEVENTH", @"EIGTH", @"NINTH", @"TENTH", nil];
_labelIndex = 0;

[self updateTurnLabel];

self.turnLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YOUR %@ DRAW?", self.playerLabel];
}
```

Here I call the Method i another Method:

```
-(void) flipDraws {
   self.boardView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
   [self updateTurnLabel];
   CardView *cv1 = (CardView *) self.turnedDrawViews[0];
   CardView *cv2 = (CardView *) self.turnedDrawViews[1];
   }
```

This is my Method:

```
-(void) updateTurnLabel {

self.playerLabel = [self.playerArray objectAtIndex:_labelIndex % self.playerArray.count]; _labelIndex++;
```

}

I tried it with a `for Loop` but nothing happened. I tried it with just set the `objectAtIndex:1` but my `Method` was not called.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by increases the objectAtIndex by 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
    int a;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    a = 0;
    self.playerArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"FIRST", @"SECOND", @"THIRD", @"FOURTH", @"FIFTH", @"SIXT", @"SEVENTH", @"EIGTH", @"NINTH", @"TENTH", nil];
    self.playerLabel = [self.playerArray objectAtIndex:a];
    self.turnLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YOUR %@ DRAW?", self.playerLabel];
}

-(void) updateTurnLabel {

    a +=1;
    if (!a<[playerArray count])
    {
        a = 0;
    }


    self.playerLabel = [self.playerArray objectAtIndex:a];
}
```

call self.turnLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YOUR %@ DRAW?", self.playerLabel]; after [self updateTurnLabel];

Comment: same issue as the other answers :( YOUR FIRST DRAW is in the label but it does not call the second object in my array.

Comment: Call [self updateTurnLabel]; when you need update. Or you want write 10 labels?

Comment: i call [self updateTurnLabel]; in my flipDraws Method, and i know that the flipDraw Method was called, but my label was not updated...

Comment: you need to call self.turnLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YOUR %@ DRAW?", self.playerLabel]; after  [self updateTurnLabel];

Comment: You are my Hero! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What are you adding +1 to in the method `objectAtIndex:`.

You should be maintaining a variable which tracks the current index being used, then in your method use this :

```
-(void) updateTurnLabel {
    self.playerLabel = [self.playerArray objectAtIndex:currentIndex+1];
}
```